# Returns Null when reading data from XML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, hive, scala-ide

I am trying to parse data from a XML file through Spark using `databrics` library

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import java.text.Format
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws
import org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.With
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import scala.sys.process._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
object printschema 
{
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
  {
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("printschema").setMaster("local")
      conf.set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "10000000") 
      val context = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlCotext = new SQLContext(context)
      import sqlCotext.implicits._
      val df = sqlCotext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
     .option("rowTag", "us-bibliographic-data-application")
     .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", true)
     .load("/Users/praveen/Desktop/ipa0105.xml")
    val q1= df.withColumn("document",$"application-reference.document-id.doc-number".cast(sql.types.StringType))
           .withColumn("document_number",$"application-reference.document-id.doc-number".cast(sql.types.StringType)).select("document","document_number").collect()
           for(l<-q1)
           {
             val m1=l.get(0)
             val m2=l.get(1)
             println(m1,m2)
           }         
  }
}
```

When I run the code on ScalaIDE/IntelliJ IDEA it works fine and here is my Output.

```
(14789882,14789882)
(14755945,14755945)
(14755919,14755919)
```

But, when I build a jar and execute it by using `spark-submit` it returns simply null values

OUTPUT :

```
NULL,NULL
NULL,NULL
NULL,NULL
```

Here is my Spark submit:

**`./spark-submit --jars /home/hadoop/spark-xml_2.11-0.4.0.jar --class inndata.praveen --master local[2] /home/hadoop/ip/target/scala-2.11/ip_2.11-1.0.jar`**

Comment: Spark master is running on the same machine ?

Comment: Yes running on local machine

Comment: you haven't done any action on the dataframe. dataframes are distributed in nature and are not located in driver node. while you are printing in driver node. so you have find a way to collect the dataframe in the driver by doing some action functions.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, when i apply collect() action on dataframe df, i get the same result    i.e, Null

Comment: can you update the question with changes that you did. And update with full command of spark-submit

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Question Updated

Comment: thanks . can you try `ql.show(false)` and confirm if the dataframe is being formed.?